# Java Hailstone Sequence

Tags: java, sequence

I have to do a Hailstone Sequence code in Java for example it should go like this:

```
10 5 16 8 4 2 1 4 2 1
```

Mine goes like this:

```
10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

How to fix this?

This is my code:

```
static int counter; 

static int HailstoneNumbers(int Number) 
{ 

    System.out.print(Number+ " ");

    if (Number == 1 && counter == 0) { 
        return counter; 
    }  
    else if (Number == 1 && counter != 0) { 
        counter++; 
        return counter; 
    }  
    else if (Number % 2 == 0) { 
        counter++; 
        HailstoneNumbers(Number / 2); 
    }  
    else if (Number % 2 != 0) { 
        counter++; 
        HailstoneNumbers(3 * Number + 1); 
    } 
    return counter; 
} 


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int Number;

    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    System.out.println("What is your intial value? ");
    Number = reader.readInt();

    int x; 

    x = HailstoneNumbers(Number); 

    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("Number of Steps: " +x); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hailstone Program in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092721/hailstone-program-in-java)

Comment: No, your sequence is correct. Also known under the name Collatz. At 1 it ends. Otherwise there would be an endless sequence /4 2 1/

Answer (score 0):

Your code *explicitly* says to stop the sequence when it reaches the number 1.  Maybe you meant the behavior to be different depending on the value of counter, but it isn't clear why it should *not* stop at the first 1 but *should* stop at the second (as `counter` will not be 0 for either).

Comment: Scott Hunter, so what do you think I should change to make it not stop at 1?

Comment: If it never stops at 1, it never stops.

Comment: Scott Hunter, whenever I keep changing Number == 1 to 0 the program doesn't run correctly or I get an error. Could you provide any code that would change it to not stop at 1. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it never stops at 1, it never stops.